# Is overwriting a frontend framework's CSS with your own in a separate style sheet the most efficient way?

Tags: css, web, frontend

Let's say for example I am using some sort of frontend framework to design a website such as Foundation or Bootstrap.

I want to customize certain parts of the design in order to give it a unique feel, one that is different from the regular frontend look of it.  What I have been doing is including the CSS for the framework then right after include another CSS, in which I write custom styles for the same classes that are used within the framework so they look like my unique look.

Is this the best way to go about customizing some sort of frontend framework like this, and if not, what would the cons be?  Or is there a better way?

I realize one more request for a style page but other than that I can really only think that the browser might need to do a little more work when rendering the page.  I do this so I don't have to go in and find every single element and class that I want changed within the framework's CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would never modify the original framework. Good practice is to include the modified classes in a separate style sheet as you have mentioned.

The advantages is you have never modified the original which could introduce bugs and to convert back to the default frameworks style will be as easy as removing your added styles.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, I would modify the original css to your own design. This way your not making the user download one css file that just over rights the other css file. Also, I think it would make debugging easier as you only have to look in one file rather than two.

Answer (score 0):

That is the best way also you could also add classes of your own and style them if you don't want to override the css framwork classes

Comment: Ok thanks. That makes a lot of sense, because I most likely would be adding my own classes for elements that might be separate from the framework.  So I would need a place to put those styles, as to not clutter the framework's stylesheet and have better organization.

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing this with some elements in [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/index.html) by adding `!important` tags in my main `style.css` file. There's no downside to doing this that I'm aware of.

---

```
.result-header .nav, .result-header .nav-bar {
    position: absolute !important;
    bottom: 4px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
}

.result-header .nav a, .result-header .nav-bar a {
    padding: 1px 8px !important;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    border-radius: 4px !important;
}
```

---

Not every css element will need the `!important`, but it doesn't hurt to add it for each one. Just make sure you hierarchy your css (`.result-header .nav-bar`) if you only want to change the styling for a certain section.

---

If you're planning on changing the core foundation of the themes style (`.nav-bar`), you could edit the original file (making sure to backup anything you change), but I'd probably be best to create a whole separate stylesheet with only the theme changes and include it after the theme's original CSS:

---

```
.nav, .nav-bar {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px;
}

.nav a, .nav-bar a {
    padding: 1px 8px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will probably use the !important tag for this from now on then, just to be safe.

Comment: Adding the !important tag is just adding extra bloat, should only use if necessary. If your CSS is setup to declare the framework first then your styles, it will overwrite the framework style and use yours.

Comment: Forgot to remove them from the second block of code. luke2012 is correct.

Comment: `!important` is a blunt instrument. Better is to make your selectors more specific than the framework's selectors.